What does 想起来 mean?
Does 想起来 have a meaning of suddenness? As in, is it used when you recall something with no intention of recalling it, e.g. "recall out of nowhere"? Or is it used actively, as in "recall something after trying to recall it"? Or can it be used both ways?

想起来 =(idea, memory) come to one's mind, intentionally or accidentally

Can you provide an example of "recall something with no intention of recalling it"? I guess that you meant to say "Accidentally think of something (无意間想起来)"

Both.
If you want to emphasis the suddenness, you can use 突然想起来.

The expression 想起来 should be broken down into 想 and 起来. since it doesn't really have a completely unpredictable meaning in combination.  Both parts can have many meanings.
The trickiest part of this expression is typically understanding the role of 起来.
Used after 想, 起来 typically has one of three uses:

indicating the completeness or effectiveness.  E.g., 我想起来了 ("I remember now" or, literally, "I have thought of it now.")

indicating the start or continuation of an action.  (The previous example could be interpreted this way.)  This nuance is what can give an impression of suddenness.

creating a verbal topic that is roughly equivalent to "when it comes to.." or "upon...," sometimes translated with an English intransitive or middle verb.  E.g. 想起来很不容易 ("When you think about it, it's really not easy")



Remember something after someone mentioned it:
你这一提，我倒的确想起来了。
I do remember, now (that) you mention it.
Something you'd rather not remember but can't forget:
时至今日，回想起来，仍然难过。
Even now the thought of it agonises me.
Think about something and remember:
我现在想起来了，它们是白色的。
They're white, now I think about it.

Actually, it works both way:

The memory been triggered/recalled from nowhere.

你这么一说让我想起来当初有个朋友也有这样的本领。

The memory has been recalled finally, or you've finally remembered it.

你这么一提醒我终于想起来那个朋友的名字了。
